# tic tac toe game how to replace the board with x's and o's?

Tags: java, methods

Ok it is my first time in a computer class and i have been having some trouble i have an assignment were i have to make a tic tac toe game, using the methods that the teacher gave us and i am not allowed to change the main method. im suppose to create a board that asks the user if they want a 4x4 5x5 or 6x6 and display it using '-'s. I have done that part correctly but i have no idea how to replace the board with the users input of what row and column they want to put their move.

My main problem is in the getMove method. I don't know how to get the input to replace the '-' with an x or o.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab7 {
public static int currentPlayer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char [] [] board; char win; char player;
        Random randy = new Random();
        int size = getBoardSize();

        while(size >= 4) {
            board = createEmptyBoard( size );
            player = getStartingPlayer(randy);
            do {
                getMove(board, player);
                player = player=='O'?'X':'O'; 
                win = checkForWin(board);
            } while(win == 'N'); 
            if(win == 'F'){
                System.out.printf("\nThe board is Full: no Winner\n");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("\nThe winner is %c\n", win);
            }
            displayBoard(board);
            size = getBoardSize();

        } 
    } 

    public static int getBoardSize() {
        int retval;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.printf("Enter board size 4, 5, 6 or -1 to quit: ");
            retval = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        } while(retval != 4 && retval != 5 
                && retval != 6 && retval != -1);
        keyboard.nextLine(); 

        return retval; 
    }

    public static char getStartingPlayer(Random rangen){
        char retval = 'X'; 



        System.out.printf("\n\tNew Game. Starting player is %c\n", retval);
        return retval;
    } 

    public static char [][] createEmptyBoard(int size) {
        char [] [] board = new char [size][size];
        // two loops to fill cells with '-'
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if ((board[i][j] == 'x') || (board[i][j] == 'o'))
                System.out.print(" " + board[i][j]);
            else
                System.out.print(" -");
        System.out.println();
    } return board;
    }



public static void getMove(char [][] board, char player){
 int row;
int column;

    System.out.printf("Player %c move\n", player);
    System.out.print("Enter Row:");
    System.out.println();


      displayBoard(board);  
    }

    public static void displayBoard(char [][] board) {     

    } 

    public static char checkForWin(char [][] board){
        char retval = 'F';

        return retval; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Given that checkForWin() always returns 'F', which apparently signifies a full board, it doesn't seem like this program does what it is supposed to. It will end after one turn every time.

Comment: I havent finished that part i dont know how to replace a '-' with a x or an o if i cant do that then idk how to check for a win yet

Answer (score 0):

If you know how, clear the screen and redraw the board. I doubt that would be required in a beginning computer class though. Just re-print the board on every turn.